# Estimating range predicate with SQL Server statistics histogram

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, query-performance, database-optimization

I would like to ask how does SQL Server can estimate those rows in the below query, If it use histogram to calculate the estimate rows, how does it do. any hints or links to the answer are highly appreciate.

```
 use AdventureWorks2012
go
select *
from sales.SalesOrderDetail 
where SalesOrderID between 43792 and 44000
option (recompile)
```

[this is execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZwzV.png)

[this is statistics info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu1mL.png)

Answer (score 4):

SQLSERVER constructs statistics of the column to analyze data distribution in that column and based on that histogram it derives estimations

lets take a small example to understand data more..

```
drop table t1

create table t1
(
id int 
)

insert into t1
select top 300 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
from   master..spt_values t1 
       cross join master..spt_values t2

go 3



select * from t1 where id=1



dbcc show_statistics('t1','_WA_Sys_00000001_29572725')
```

dbcc gives me below historgram

```
   RANGE_HI_KEY RANGE_ROWS  EQ_ROWS DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS AVG_RANGE_ROWS
1                   0          3          0                1
3                   3          3          1                3
4                   0          3          0                1
6                   3          3          1                3
8                   3          3          1                3
10                  3          3          1                3
```

Above is a snip of dbcc output.Before jumping into explaining what those mean.Lets understand how data is distributed in the table

there are 300 rows from 1 to 300,duplicated 3 times.So total count of rows is 900

Now lets understand what those columns mean

**RANGE_HI_KEY**    :

sql server used the values in this column as top keys to construct histogram,since histogram is limited to only 200 steps..It choose
rows used to construct histogram  ..this will be limited to 200 steps.in this case the values are 1,3,4,6 and so on

**RANGE_ROWS**:

This number shows the number of rows within the step that are greater than the previous top key and the current top key, but not equal to either.

rows >1 and <3 and so on

**EQ_ROWS :**

Specifies how many rows are exactly equa1 to top value .in this case ,it is = 1 ,3 and so on

**DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS :**

These are the distinct count of rows within a step. If all the rows are unique, then the RANGE_ROWS and the DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS will be equal.

distinct rows where value >1 and <3 and so on

**AVG_RANGE_ROWS:**

This represents the average number of rows equal to a key value within the step,which means avg number of rows equal to top key ie., 1,3 and so on

**some demo queries **

```
select * from id=1
```

we know EQ_rows for 1 has a value of 3,so you can see estimated rows as 3

this is for simple equal query,but how does it work for multiple predicates like the one in your case..

Bart Duncan provides some insights

> The optimizer has a number of ways to estimate cardinality, none of which are completely foolproof.
>
> If the predicate is simple like “column=123” and if the search value happens to be a histogram endpoint (RANGE_HI_KEY), then EQ_ROWS can be used for a very accurate estimate.
>
> If the search value happens to fall between two step endpoints, then the average density of values in that particular histogram step is used to estimate predicate selectivity and operator cardinality.
>
> If the specific search value is not known at compile time, the next best option is to use average column density (“All density”), which can be used to calculate the number of rows that will match an average value in the column.
>
> In some cases none of the above are possible and optimizer has to resort to a “magic number”-based estimate.  For example, it might make a totally blind guess that 10% of the rows will be returned, where the “10%” value would be hardcoded in the optimizer’s code rather than being derived from statistics.

**further references and reading :**

https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/cardinality-estimation-for-multiple-predicates
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2011/01/25/query-tuning-fundamentals-density-predicates-selectivity-and-cardinality/

Comment: Thanks for your support, your answer is not truly what I expected but from your hints I could guess the answer for myself. Actually, my question was not clear enough, the real question is when a predicate fall between two steps (two RANGE_HI_KEY value) how can we calculate the estimated row count? the query looks like
select *
from sales.SalesOrderDetail 
where SalesOrderID < 43660
I said "guess" because I did not find out any article talk about this, but I found that SQL Server might use the interpolation method to do???

Comment: If then we could not know exactly which formula SQL Server used?